# Is there a sequence in $l^2$ such that $\sum \frac{x_k}{\sqrt{k}}$ diverges?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is there a sequence in $l^2$ such that $\sum \frac{x_k}{\sqrt{k}}$ diverges?

I ask this question because I try to find a functional on $l^2$ that is unbounded on sequence {$1/\sqrt{n}$}.

I think this sequence should decrease faster than $1/\sqrt{n}$ so it converge in $l^2$ but not fast enough to make $\sum \frac{x_k}{\sqrt{k}}$ converges. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you studied $x_k=k^a$ for $a>0$?

Comment: $1/\sqrt{n}\notin \ell^2$ as it is not square summable.

Comment: $1/(\sqrt n \ln n)$.

Comment: @QC_QAOA You are right. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMitra this is not in l2

Comment: It is indeed in $\ell_2$ (by the Integral test, e.g.).

Comment: @DavidMitra I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: For any $(a_n)\notin \ell^2$ there is a sequence $(b_n)\in \ell^2$ such that the series $\sum a_nb_n$ diverges.

Comment: I'm sorry for my stupid comment above.  I confess it was not sufficiently thought out!